# How to Express a 2-hour Interval from Now Backwards in SQL in DBVisualizer

Tags: sql, intervals, vertica

in Vertica DB, I need to build a query selecting all rows with the timestamp within the past period of two hours from now. This doesn't work, however:

```
select * from device_health_1
where timeframe >= current_timestamp - interval 2 hour
```

NOW() doesn't seem to work, either.
Would appreciate suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: what database you are using? tag the actual database engine you are sing,

Comment: DBVisualizer is a SQL client that can connect to many different database products and is irrelevant for this question. (Note that the query in your question is non-standard SQL)

Comment: Sorry, Vertica DB

Comment: What "doesn't work" actually means? If your computer accidentally turned off, then it "doesn't work" also, but has nothing about the SQL code. Please provide sample data and desired output along with your current output and description, why do you consider it wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM device_health_1
WHERE timeframe >= current_timestamp - interval '2 hour'
```

The error was missing single quotes. Working now, thanks!